# VirtueMart Error - This webpage is not available ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

Hi I am getting an "This webpage is not available ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" error on the backend of a joomla website that I am maintaining recently.

I have contacted Blacknight to see what the problem was and I was told it was to do with line 225 in the virtuemart extension:

```
if ($iBrowseCol == $BrowseProducts_per_row || $iBrowseProduct == $BrowseTotalProducts) {?>
```

I have added the paragraph of code if someone things the problem is else where:

```
<?php
$iBrowseProduct ++;

// Do we need to close the current row now?
if ($iBrowseCol == $BrowseProducts_per_row || $iBrowseProduct == $BrowseTotalProducts) {?>
    </div>
    <?php
     $iBrowseCol = 1;
   } else {
     $iBrowseCol ++;
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem with another shopping cart and it was because I turn on the Joomla gzip.

Go to Joomla global configuration - Server - Gzip Page Compression - No

This is how I fixed the issue on my site.

Comment: Thanks for the information/tip. Will give this a go and get back to you :)